# sObject.get(fieldname) detects changes from null to blank?

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex, text

I was writing a utility class which can give the names of the fields that changed during an update trigger (I have a specific set of fields that i want to track, not all fields). My code snippet is below.

My concern is, if the field is a text field, and it changes from empty string to null (or vice-versa), will this code detect it as a change? After writing my code, i tried using workbench to test it out, but its not helping. I took a record where a text field is null (got it through SOQL query). Then used Apex execute to update it to blank field (sampleRecord.fieldName__c = '';). But querying it again still shows the field as null. So i am unable to test my implementation.

```
public Map<Id,Set<String>> findFieldChanges(Map<Id,sObject> oldRecordsMap, Map<Id,sObject> newRecordsMap, Set<String> fieldsToBeTracked){
        Map<Id,Set<String>> recIdToFieldNamesMap = new Map<Id,Set<String>>();
        for(sObject currOldRecord : oldRecordsMap.values()){
            sObject currNewRecord = newRecordsMap.get(currOldRecord.Id);
            for(String currField : fieldsToBeTracked){
                if(currOldRecord.get(currField) != currNewRecord.get(currField)){
                    if(!recIdToFieldNamesMap.containsKey(currOldRecord.Id)){
                        recIdToFieldNamesMap.put(currOldRecord.Id, new Set<String>());
                    }
                    (recIdToFieldNamesMap.get(currOldRecord.Id)).add(currField);
                }
            }
        }
        return recIdToFieldNamesMap;
    }
```

The line

```
if(currOldRecord.get(currField) != currNewRecord.get(currField))
```

is what i am curious about. If it a text field, does it differentiate between null and blank?

Comment: null is not the same as '' (empty string), but the system automatically converts empty strings to null values when you perform a DML operation, so inside the trigger context, the field will never have an empty string. Adrian's answer demonstrates this principle. You never have to worry about checking for '' as a possible field value when you get a record directly from the database.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I figured that. And as Adrian pointed out, trigger.old will always have null. BUT trigger.new could have empty string (let's assume it goes through additional code which tries to set a text field to empty string, and then it encounters my generic method).

its a problem for me if a text field going from null to empty is detected as a change. In the code snipped written here, is there a way to take into consideration? In the above code (where it is for generic sObject) can we somehow determine the type of the field specified by parameter currField?

Comment: @user2957592 Is your generic code running in `after update`? If so, then my point still stands. There will never be an empty string in your fields. Further, if you're using `before update` for whatever reason, you will want to use `after update` instead, because triggers run in an indeterminate order, so you cannot guarantee you have the final state of the fields until `after update` starts, because the records will be locked then.

Comment: @user2957592 If you really, *really* need to check for empty strings, which I doubt you really do, you can use `if(currOldRecord.get(currField) != currNewRecord.get(currField) && currNewRecord.get(currField) != '')` Just be aware that you're probably wasting CPU time for a situation that will never occur.

Answer (score 2):

The "old" value would only ever be `null`, never the empty string (`''`). These two values are *not* equal, so yes your code will detect the change if you set the field to the empty string instead of nulling it out.

```
for (MyObject__c record : trigger.new)
{
    record.TextField__c = '';
    // considered a change

    record.TextField__c = null;
    // not considered a change
}
```

You can also demonstrate to yourself the database stores values as null by running a unit test like the following:

```
static testMethod void testNullField()
{
    MyObject__c record = new MyObject__c(TextField__c='');

    Test.startTest();
        insert record;
    Test.stopTest();

    record = [SELECT TextField__c FROM MyObject__c WHERE Id = :record.Id];
    system.assertEquals(null, record.TextField__c, 'The field should be null, not blank');
}
```

Comment: - In the code snippet written in original question, is there a way to determine if currField is a text field? Because then i can add the condition if(current field is a text field){ consider null and blank as same}

Comment: @user I would advise you to just use null rather than the empty string in your code which performs field updates.